# SMTP server Sending multiple emails

Tags: java, smtp, smtpclient

I am working with SMTP server and found out an issue.

1) SMTP server is not down:  In this case, the SMTP server is busy servicing email requests concurrently and continuously for more than 5 minutes (I'm sending bulk mails).  At some point of time during servicing, it is not returning or throwing any exceptions to the Java/JavaMail program.  In fact, I've experienced this kind of situation in my real time.  In case, if I've not set both mail.smtp.timeout and mail.smtp.connectiontimeout properties within my code, it would never return and goes into infinite state.

If i do set my mail.smtp.connectiontimeout and mail.smtp.timeout, how can I test it?
How can we simulate/reproduce this kind of situation?  Any ideas?

2) Also another issue is caused by networking issue where I send the request to SMTP form my java code, and it is queued. I am not sure what happens (I dont have a java loop) but the SMTP sends out multiple emails to the same person. Is it because the SMTP did not send back an response? Should the code not timeout after 3000?

Below is my code

```
props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 3000);
props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 3000);
SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");
/ do some message setting here /
 transport.connect(); 
             int SMTPCodeBeforeSendingMessage = transport.getLastReturnCode();
             logger.debug("Connection Code for SMTP connection after connect before sending mesasge" + SMTPCodeBeforeSendingMessage);

             transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients()); 

             String SMTPresponse = transport.getLastServerResponse(); 
             logger.debug("SMTP resposne after sending message" + SMTPresponse);
             transport.close();
```

Comment: 1) How many message do you want to send? [100/1_000/10_000/...] 2) Which SMTP server do you contact? sendmail/postfix/exim/... 3) Are you postmaster/administrator f the SMTP server?

Comment: Sometimes 1 sometimes 10 at the max. I contact an internal SMTP server of the organization (already set up) and I am not the administrator of the SMTP server.